# instead of firstordefault what can i use to get all the values

Tags: linq

Below is the code, it just returns only the first record, because of the FirstOrDefault. How can i change it to retrieve all elements?

```
        var fValue = bList.Cast<String>()Where(t => t.StartsWith(sValue,      StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToList();
```

Comment: bList is a list of String?

Comment: Replace the words "FirstOrDefault" with "Where". Done.

Comment: Familiarize yourself with the extension methods on `Enumerable`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341635.aspx . Knowing what each does and how to use them will help you leverage Linq to improve your code where applicable.

Comment: Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string'

Comment: If you want all the matches, then don't type the variable to contain those matches to a type that can only contain one of them.

Comment: What variable should i use to contain more than one?

Comment: Use `var` to implicitly type the variable (as shown in an answer below) or explicitly type it to `IEnumerable<string>`, as indicated in the error message.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram
When i run my program my results say this
System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereEnumerablelIterator`1{System String}

Comment: or if you want all the answers in one string you can add .Aggregate((x,y) => x + "," + y);   after the where and it will make a comma separated string of all the strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var fValues = bList.Cast<String>()
       .Where(t =>t.StartsWith(sValue, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
       .ToList();
```

if you want to make a string to show all your values

```
var fValue = bList.Cast<String>()
       .Where(t =>t.StartsWith(sValue, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
       .Aggregate((x,y) => x + "\r\n" + y);
```

Comment: it comes up this in my results 
System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereEnumerablelIterator`1{System String}

Comment: you'd need to show more code for me to work out where you are going wrong

Comment: @KChunman  I updated my answer, the second one makes one big string from all the other strings.   at the moment I've made each string go on a different line "\r\n" you can just put " " if you want spaces between each one

Comment: Thanks Keith your my hero :D